# Prove Nth derivative expression by induction

Tags: derivatives, proof-verification, induction

I am given the function $f(x) = \sqrt{3x+5}$

I have calculated the expression of the nth derivative to be

$$f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot(2n-3)!!}{2^n}\cdot(3x+5)^{-(2n-1)/2}\cdot3$$

How would I prove this expression to be true by induction?

Comment: Differentiate your expression for $f^{(n)}(x)$ with respect to $x$, and you should get $f^{(n+1)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^n+1\cdot-|2n-1|!!}{2^{n+1}}\cdot(3x+5)^{-(2n+1)/2}\cdot3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to show that: $$f^{(n+1)}(x)=\frac{(-1)^{n}\cdot(2n-1)!!}{2^{n+1}}\cdot(3x+5)^{-(2n+1)/2}\cdot3 = \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(f(x))\right)=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{(-1)^{n+1}\cdot(2n-3)!!}{2^n}\cdot(3x+5)^{-(2n-1)/2}\cdot3\right).$$

I trust that you can differentiate the last expression.

Comment: How does this prove the n+1 case? Don't I need to show that this expression is equal to a " n plus 1th" derivative by taking that derivative? If so, how do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: I mean how do you take the nth derivative, if you don't know what n is? How do you derive n times? Am I going down the completely wrong path here?

Comment: You just treat $n$ as a constant. The only variable you are differentiating with respect to is $x$. Is the expression for the derivative from literature or did you derive it yourself?

Comment: I derived the function and I understand how to differentiate the last expression, I just have trouble understanding how that proves the expression through induction.

Comment: OMG. Sorry, I just got it. It's late haha. Thanks a lot.